# Changing text of IBOutlet UILabel via delegate

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to change the text of an UILabel that is created via Storyboard. I have two ViewControllers, FirstViewController and SecondViewController. I dismiss the SecondViewController, call the method in the SecondViewController, the delegate method is called in the FirstViewController but the UILabel is nil.
Any idea why?

SecondViewController

```
-(void)back {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
    [self.delegate points:@"10"];
}
```

FirstViewController

```
-(void)points:(NSString *)point {
     labelPoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %@", point]; 
}
```

Comment: check if labelPoints is nil ?

Comment: That is what I said. It is nil. But why?

Comment: Did you link your IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes it is linked. When I have a breakpoint in my viewDidLoad method 'labelPoints' is not nil

Comment: maybe because you didn't display on the screen ?

Comment: It's not on the screen, yes. I pop the SecondViewController, the delegate gets called, then the FirstViewController will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Is your FirstViewController rootViewController? Else pushing to rootViewController will remove First ViewController from stack. From Second View Controller first call delegate and then popViewController as below.

```
 -(void)back {
    [self.delegate points:@"10"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  

 }
```

Comment: It is my rootViewController, both would work though. First calling the delegate and then popping the view Controller does not change anything.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you label is created in first view? Is in in interface builder or in code?

Comment: Interface builder - it is an IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

You're popping the VC before you set the value. I would pop from your delegate object like this:

```
-(void)back { 
     [self.delegate points:@"10"];
    }

-(void)points:(NSString *)point {
    labelPoints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %@", point];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:YES];
}
```

If this doesn't solve it, then you likely have another issue besides this one and would have to post more code.

Answer (score 0):

## Delay in setting text in UILabel worked for me

For example when delegate calls method like this:

```
[self.delegate selectedAttendee:dictAttendee];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

#### This didn't worked for me:

```
-(void)selectedAttendee:(NSDictionary *)dictAttendee
{
  lblMessageTo.text = [dictAttendee objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

### Solution

```
-(void)selectedAttendee:(NSDictionary *)dictAttendee
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(addTextInMessageTo:) withObject:dictAttendee afterDelay:0.3];
}

-(void)addTextInMessageTo:(NSDictionary *)dictAttendee
{
   lblMessageTo.text = [dictAttendee objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```